# Shaded polygons in R with linear constraints

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon

I have 6 linear constraints. I know how to find solution to this problem both by hand and via `r`. I am looking for an easy way to obtain illustration for a feasible region.

I tried `ggplot2` to do so without any success.

Here are the constraints: `x1 >= 0, x2 >= 0, x2 <= 10` and the `x2 <= 12 - 2/5 * x1`, `x2 <= 18 - x1`, `x2 <= 18 - x1`

```
require(ggplot2)

# x2 <= 12 - 2/5*x1
fun1 = function(x1){
     x2 = 12 - 2/5*x1
     return(x2)
}

# x2 <= 18 - x1
fun2 = function(x1){
    x2 = 18 - x1
    return(x2)
}

# x2 = 44 - 3*x1
fun3 = function(x1){
    x2 = 44 - 3*x1
    return(x2)
}

x1 = seq(0,20)
mydf = data.frame(x1, fun1(x1), fun2(x1),fun3(x1),rep(10,length(x1)))
names(mydf) = c('x1','y1','y2','y3','y4')
mydf$y5 = rep(0,length(x1))

p0 = ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x1)) + 
     coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,10),xlim = c(0,20))+                      
     geom_line(aes(y = y1), colour = 'blue') +
     geom_line(aes(y = y2), colour = 'green') +
     geom_line(aes(y = y3), colour = 'red') +
     geom_line(aes(y = y4), colour = 'purple') +
     geom_line(aes(y = y5), colour = 'black')

p0 +  geom_area(aes(y = pmin(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)), fill = 'gray60')
```

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT**: removing last `y5` from the `pmin` function does the trick:

```
 p0 +  geom_area(aes(y = pmin(y1,y2,y3,y4,y5)), fill = 'gray60')
```

Comment: I think I figured out my own error. Since I am bounding the region to be in a positive quadrant small correction to the las line will do the trick. I update my original posting.

Comment: Good question @notrockstar. Have you tried to shade the feasible region?

Comment: I do not know of any graphical functions that will color a half-plane, but it's certainly possible to simulate such be putting some of the coordinates outside the range. Do you still consider this an open question?

Comment: @DWin, I sort of hacked it through `geom_area`. Could you possibly close this question for me? (I don't think I have this option available for me). Thanks!

Comment: I you have an answer, you can post it, and after a suitable interval you can accept it. It's not the same as "closing", which has a negative connotation, ... it's better since it will be available for others to learn from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the last variable `y5`. Removing it from `pmin` function did the trick.

```
p0 = ggplot(mydf, aes(x = x1)) + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,10),xlim = c(0,20))+                      
    geom_line(aes(y = y1), colour = 'blue') +
    geom_line(aes(y = y2), colour = 'green') +
    geom_line(aes(y = y3), colour = 'red') +
    geom_line(aes(y = y4), colour = 'purple') +
    geom_line(aes(y = y5), colour = 'black')

p0 +  geom_area(aes(y = pmin(y1,y2,y3,y4)), fill = 'gray60')
```